# Can I rename my offline profile in Battlefield 2?

Tags: battlefield-2

I'd like to rename my offline profile in Battlefield 2. The offline profile is the one I use for playing over a LAN.

I see there are two options:

1. Modify a file/registry setting somewhere to rename my offline profile
2. Manually create a new profile, trying to remember the settings from the current one

Can anyone help with option 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `~\Documents\Battlefield 2\Profiles` folder, you can find various numbered folders containing profile data. Inside them you'll find the following files:

- **`Profile.con`**: contains your login information such as name, nickname and GameSpy account information.
- **Everything else**: your game settings.

All these are text files, which you can manually edit.

You can find out which profile was used last by reading the `Global.con` file.

1. **In order to rename your profile**, you need to edit the following two lines:

   ```
   LocalProfile.setName "name"
   LocalProfile.setNick "name"
   ```

   Change `name` to your desired name. The `setNick` command defines the name that is displayed on the login screen. The `setName` defines your in-game name, as seen on the scoreboard.

   I am not sure if this works with online profiles.
2. **If you want to create another profile**, you can save yourself the trouble of manually configuring the game again by copying all files but `Profile.con` in your old profile directory to the new one.

Comment: This is a great answer! Be advised that the "~" refers to your user's home directory. On Windows 7, this meant my Battlefield 2 profile was in c:\Users\YOURNAME\Documents\Battlefield 2\Profiles.